# Why are network exceptions raised by Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient of type System.Exception instead of something more specific?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winrt-httpclient

Whenever I use the [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient) class to make HTTP requests, I always handle network exceptions like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;

try
{
    response = await httpClent.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com"));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Most likely a network exception.
    // Inspect e.HResult value to see what the specific error was.
}
```

But now I'll catch all exceptions instead of just network exceptions, especially if the try block encompasses more than just the `httpClient.GetAsync` call.

Various exception HRESULTs are already converted into appropriate managed types automatically at the ABI layer (e.g. E_OUTOFMEMORY is projected to System.OutOfMemoryException), so why are network exceptions not projected in a similar manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a very small number of exception types defined by WinRT, and a limited number of `HRESULT`s that will project specially into C#.

In general, the WinRT API design pattern *avoids* exceptions for everything except things that are programming errors and should be discovered at design-time (invalid arguments, missing capabilities, etc) or things that you can't really recover from (such as out-of-memory). You should avoid handling these types of exceptions with `try` \ `catch` because they represent bugs in your app or an inability of the system to keep running your app.

Instead, WinRT prefers to have methods succeed but return objects with status codes in them (eg, [`ResponseCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode.aspx)) that you can query to see whether the method completed successfully or not.

The reasoning for this is that many developers fail to handle exceptions (due to not fully testing their app under different configurations). An unhandled exception is *guaranteed* to bring down the process, which isn't a great experience for customers, but a return value that indicates failure can often be handled by apps, either because they were already checking the status for other reasons (eg, you probably always want to check the HTTP status, whether you got an error or not) or because the code is already resilient to "empty" results (eg, `foreach` over an empty list is well-defined).

Not all APIs follow this pattern - especially those designed early on in Windows 8 -- but it is a pattern you should see in most WinRT APIs. You will also notice a lot of `Try`-style APIs in WinRT that attempt to do something and return `true` or `false` rather than throwing an exception. So for the most part, your code should be free of `try` / `catch` blocks around WinRT API calls, although you might still need to use them for your own code or 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: How would you deal with the example in the Question? The only way seems to be catch the general Exception and inspect the HResult.

Comment: Yes, that is the only real way to handle the exceptions that don't have specific projections

Comment: I think this is a good answer but think it'd be better with a little extra guidance - as per tagy22's comment.  E.g. thoughts on using response.IsSuccessStatusCode

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` class exceptions are not automatically wrapped in appropriate managed types, but (thankfully!) there is a method which allows to get the actual reason -- [Windows.Web.WebError.GetStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.weberror.getstatus.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

For example:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://www.example.com"));

    try
    {
        // Http-errors are returned in the response, and no exception is thrown.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WebErrorStatus error = WebError.GetStatus(ex.HResult);
        // For example, if your device could not connect to the internet at all,
        // the error would be WebErrorStatus.HostNameNotResolved.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have been struggling a bit to decide how to handle errors (particularly network related ones) when using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient in UWP apps.

The pattern I settled on was to return an object (which I can return using a Task) that contains either the information or the exception:

```
private class MyResponseObject
{
  public string Data = string.Empty;
  // Alternatively you could return the HttpResponseMessage (I guess).
  //public HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage;

  public Exception Exception = null;
}
```

And specifically, to make use of checking the responses IsSuccessStatusCode property immediately after getting the response back:

```
private async Task<MyResponseObject> CallService(Uri url)
{
    MyResponseObject r = new MyResponseObject();

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // do something with the information successfully received
            r.Data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something with the exception
        r.Exception = ex;
    }

    return r;
}
```